# Stuck on search function for multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a page with multiple posts, each post has a location and department & title.

I implemented the search function for "word search" and it works fine, but in addition to this I have two Dropdown menus for location & department, they get their content from two different table.

I am kind of stuck and don't know why it doesn't work, here is my controller code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('titel')->get();
    $standorts = Standort::orderBy('standort_name')->get();
    $abteilungs = Abteilung::orderBy('abteilung_name')->get();

    if ($request->filled('s') || $request->has('standort') || $request->has('abteilung')) {

        $word = strtolower($request->get('s'));
        $location = $request->standort;
        $dep = $request->abteilung;
        $query = strtolower($request->get('s'));

        $posts = $posts->filter(function ($post) use ($dep, $word, $location) {
            if (
                Str::contains(strtolower($post->Titel), $word) ||
                Post::where('standort_name') == $location
                || Post::where('abteilung_name') == $dep
            ) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        });
    }

    return view('posts.overview', [
        'posts'      => $posts,
        'standorts'  => $standorts,
        'abteilungs' => $abteilungs,
    ]);
}
```

Here is my blade code:

```
<form class="mb-5 flex justify-left grid grid-cols-4 gap-x-20" action=" {{ route('overview') }}"
      method="get">
    <div class="w-full h-12 text-left col-start-1 col-end-1">
        <input placeholder="Schlagwort" type="text" id="s" name="s" value="{{ request()->get('s') }}"
               class="mb-2 w-full h-full bg-white bg-opacity-95 rounded focus:ring-2 border border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base outline-none text-gray-700 text-xl py-1 px-3 leading-8">
    </div>

    <div class="text-left mb-4 h-12">
        <select name="abteilung" id="abteilung" class="h-full w-full flex justify-center bg-white bg-opacity-95 rounded focus:ring-2 border border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base outline-none text-gray-700 text-lg text-center leading-8">

            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Abteilung</option>
            @foreach($abteilungs as $abteilung)
                <option value="{{ $abteilung->abteilung_name }}">{{ $abteilung->abteilung_name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="text-left mb-4 h-12">
        <select name="standort" id="standort" class="h-full w-full flex justify-center bg-white bg-opacity-95 rounded focus:ring-2 border border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base outline-none text-gray-700 text-lg text-center leading-8">

            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Standort</option>
            @foreach($standorts as $standort)
                <option value="{{ $standort->standort_name }}">{{ $standort->standort_name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <button class="col-start-4 col-end-4 w-11/12 h-12 text-white text-2xl px-4 py-2 rounded text-base font-medium bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 float-right shadow transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">
        Suchen
    </button>
</form>
```

When I dd this part:

```
$word = strtolower($request->get('s'));
$location = $request->standort;
$dep = $request->abteilung;
```

I get the correct attributes, for instance a word like "HR", a location like "Munich" and a department like "Finance".
When I perform the search though for a specific department all posts are gone.

Edit for clarity:
The goal is that a user can search for a word in a title, a location and department all in one request, and only the post where each is present gets shown.

Edit Relation Models:

Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'titel',
        'startdate',
        'enddate',
        'beschreibung',
        'standort',
        'type_name',
        'abteilung_name',
        'kontakt',
        'isActive',
        'lebenslauf',
        'zeugnisse',
        'anschreiben',
        'weitere_Doks',
        'is_Permitted',
        'job_start',
    ];

    public function location() {
        return $this->hasOne(Standort::class);
    }

    public function job_type() {
        return $this->hasOne(Jobtypes::class);
    }
    
}
```

Abteilung Model:

```
class Abteilung extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'abteilung_name',
    ];
    
    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Standort Model:

```
class Standort extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'abteilung_name',
    ];

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry my comment won't be directly related to the issue you're facing, but i would mention that with your current code you'll end up with memory problem very quick, especially because you're filtering the `posts` after getting them from the `DB` without having a `limit` clause or `pagination` ?! I mean if you have, say thousands of `post`s, you are getting all of them at once which may lead to a disaster. Why not filtering the records at the query level using `Eloquent` ?

Comment: @ths thank you for the heads up, I don't have pagination at the moment since it is only a few post and I tinker so much with the code because I cant get it to work with the multiple parameters. As soon as I got it to work I will use pagination :) I saw two tutorials and neither of them used "Eloquent". I will have a look at it, thank you! Have a nice day

Comment: So, can you elaborate more on the different databases you spoke of, i mean i dont see any sign of a second connection being used on the models. Or do you mean different tables maybe ?!

Comment: @ths ah yeah, I always mess it up. It is a different table, not different database. I edit the question

Comment: Yes i though of that. So are these tables related ? (guessing you're using 3 tables as am seeing 3 models being used in your code).

Comment: @ths there is no foreign key or something like that, but in the Model of the Post class there are two methods with "hasONe(Standort::class)" as body

Comment: Can you add the relation methods of your models to your question.

Comment: sure wait a second

Comment: @thsi got it working! I am blocked to post answers :/ can I give you the answer and you post it for me?

Comment: Glad you made it ! Anyway i recommend you work on optimizing your code.

Comment: btw, `Post::where(...)` is returning a query builder object, not the result of any query, so you are trying to compare an object to a string (the request input) ... i am assuming you meant something like `$post->field == $something`

Comment: @lagbox yeah you are right! I just spent hours on this problem and was so confused at some point. I got outside for a quick walk and when I came back it was so clear like someone planted the solution in my head :D